# KeyError when connecting to API

Tags: python, json, django, api

I'm trying to connect my Django application with the API my teammates made. I wrote a script that builds the string and then makes a request. I want to return the results to a view so I can display them on a webpage. I'm debugging the script by calling it from a terminal, but I will call the run_query method from my views file once it works. The terminal from which I'm executing the script returns this error, however:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "website/api.py", line 45, in <module>
    run_query("Statistics", 42)
  File "website/api.py", line 32, in run_query
    for result in json_response[0]['results']:
KeyError: 0
```

I've replaced some values because the data is not meant to be public.

This is what the API returns:

`{"Statistics":[{"DateTime":"2015-03-10T06:20:39Z","Percentage":33},{"DateTime":"2015-03-10T06:21:39Z","Percentage":23},(Hundred more records){"DateTime":"2015-03-19T21:15:35Z","Percentage":9}],"AverageStatistics":11}`

This is the Python script.

```
import json
import requests

def run_query(type, id):
    # Base URL
    root_url = "https://api.com/"

    if type == "Statistics":
        data_type = "Statistics"
    else:
        print("Error: Invalid type input.")

    request_url = root_url + data_type + "?Id=" + str(id)
    print request_url

    results = []

    try:
        # Connect
        response = requests.get(request_url)
        print response

        # Convert response to dictionary object
        json_response = response.json()
        print json_response

        # Loop through results
        if type == "Statistics":
            for result in json_response[0]['results']:
                results.append({
                'DateTime': result['DateTime'],
                'Percentage': result['Percentage']})

    # Catch URLError exception
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException, e:
        print "Error querying API: ", e

    return results

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print "Connecting with API..."
    run_query("Statistics", 42)
```

The line `for result in json_response[0]['results']:` is what throws the error. I've read that the response should be a list object, so 0 as the key should work, right? I've tried using "Statistics" as a key, but then Python tells me that I should've input an integer.

`print json_response` prints this:

```
{u'AverageStatistics': 11.739414713896636, u'Statistics': [{u'Percentage': 33.23, u'DateTime': u'2015-03-10T06:20:39Z'},
```

And then a lot more records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `json_response` dictionary does not have an entry with `0` as a key. According to the rest of the code, you should use `for result in json_response['Statistics']` instead of `for result in json_response[0]['results']`

Answer (score 1):

json_response in a dictionary and there is no key as '0'. That is why you are getting KeyError.

Instead use json_response['AverageStatistics'] and json_response['Statistics']